# Problem with matching regex in python in multiline string with backreference

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match the following regex :

```
((symbol_live:)\s+\"(?P<LiveSymbol>.)\")?((symbol_dead:)\s+\"(?P<DeadSymbol>.)\")?(gamefield:\s*\n\"\n(?P<Seed>(((\g<DeadSymbol>)|(\g<LiveSymbol>))+\n)+)\"\s*)?
```

the given string to search in is :

```
gamefield:
"
-------------------------------
-------------------------------
----------oo-------------------
----------oo-------------------
------------oo-----------------
------------oo-----------------
-------------------------o-----
-------------------------o-----
-------------------------o-----
-------------------------------
-------------------------------
-------------------------------
-------------------------------
"
symbol_dead: "-"
symbol_live: "o"
```

I am writing this with python RE module and I used finditer to iterate through all the possible matches.
it returns both `symbol_dead: "-"` and `symbol_live: "o"` but not the `"seed"` named group in `gamefield`

I write the following code to return the value for each group in the iteration:

```
p = re.finditer(r'((symbol_live:)\s+\"(?P<LiveSymbol>.)\")?((symbol_dead:)\s+\"(?P<DeadSymbol>.)\")?(gamefield:\s*\n\"\n(?P<Seed>(((\\g<DeadSymbol>)|(\\g<LiveSymbol>))+\n)+)\"\s*)?', string=input, flags=re.M)
for l in p:
    if 'DeadSymbol' in l.groupdict().keys() and l.groupdict()['DeadSymbol'] != None:
        print('DeadSymbol return = ' + l.groupdict()['DeadSymbol'])
    elif 'LiveSymbol' in l.groupdict().keys() and l.groupdict()['LiveSymbol'] != None:
        print('LiveSymbol return = ' + l.groupdict()['LiveSymbol'])
    elif 'Seed' in l.groupdict().keys() and l.groupdict()['Seed'] != None:
        print('Seed return = ' + l.groupdict()['Seed'])
```

When I check this in `https://regexr.com/` it works! but not works in `https://pythex.org/`
I don't know what is wrong with the regex and I need help on this! since it is becoming frustrating for me to resolve!

Comment: When i try it on regex101.com, it only matches `symbol_dead: "-"`. https://regex101.com/r/fsCfF7/1

Comment: Back-references don't persist between different iterations of the regexp. Think of them as like local variables within a match, not global variables.

Comment: I have updated the regex!

Comment: I think @Barmar is right if regex works in iterations then there should be no persistence of values for named groups which is absolutely awful!

Comment: A good way to break down an expression and get help, if not see what's wrong while breaking it down, is to use verbose regex syntax like so: https://pastebin.com/4TSnjbYL in questions. It's not really a common practice, but it can be useful. Then just include the `re.X` or re.`VERBOSE` flag

Comment: I notice, after breaking it down, that you have groups of groups. Even if that were supported, it would be unnecessary for parsing the text you have. @SasanAhmadi ... there's that and you're trying to refer to your tags with \g<> inside the same expression. \g<> is for substitution expressions with re.sub(). I think you meant (?P=<>)

Comment: The *inline backreference* syntax in Python `re` is `(?P=name)`. `\k<name>` will work with .NET or PCRE regex.

Comment: the backref is only one of a few problems with the expression btw

Comment: @Todd I have used (?P=<>) as well and it doesn't work either!

Comment: @SasanAhmadi the syntax of that is wrong btw.. a backref leaves out the angle brackets (?P=somename). Anyway, you've got quite a few issues with that expression. If you look at the pastebin I linked, you've got nested groups with iterations on them. You've got to simplify your expression for it to work. When you use parenthesis, you tell the parser to group the results between them. If you want non-grouping parenthesis, you can use `(?:    )`.

Comment: @SasanAhmadi here's some code using expressions to match your game board text: https://pastebin.com/4kf0kugr

Comment: thanks @Todd I learned something new